# How do I get to the surgery machine on level R of System Shock 1?

Tags: system-shock

On level R (the lowest floor) of System Shock 1, there's a surgery machine clearly visible near the anti-radiation chamber. It's blocked only by a force door, as seen on the screenshot below.

[image: SS1, level R, surgery machine]

I have no idea how to unlock that room and my guides couldn't help me out either this time. I'm pretty sure I completed everything else on this level, so it can't be a room that is relevant for proceeding with the story in any way.

Any ideas how to get in there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There should be a wire puzzle panel on the wall directly opposite the door which will open it (from where you're standing in that screenshot, you'd need to turn right about 90 degrees to see it).

Comment: You're absolutely right. Some guide even hinted at that, but I just didn't see it. It's semi-cleverly hidden by being embedded into a very common wall texture, but I guess that's not really an excuse for me missing it even when I was specifically looking for it. :)

Comment: Please accept my thanks that 10 years later this answer is still useful.